# Cannot access resources on VPN network

Tags: 10.04, network-manager

I managed to connect from outside to the corporate network using VPN (OpenVPN plugin of the network-manager). I get my IP address, routing tables etc set up. But I cannot access anything on that network.

I set my computer as DMZ so it's not a NAT issue. My LAN uses 192.168.123.xxx. VPN uses 10.xxx.xxx.xxx address space.

I opened Wireshark and listened to the tun0 device. Packets going out, but nothing received.

I also listened to the eth0 device. Packets are going in from and out to the VPN gateway.

I set up iptables to accept all traffic via the tun devices, but no avail.

Any ideas to make VPN work?

Answer (score 2):

Enabling the LZO compression in the advanced settings of the VPN connection solved the problem for me. (Hope this helps someone out.)